# How can I use parentheses in Django Slug?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I use parentheses in Django project slugs?
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, allow_unicode=True )

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

> A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens.

i.e. no parentheses.